# Refresh all routes in Angular js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to reload all the *routes(controllers)* without a page refresh in ***angularjs*** application.

Is this possible?

`$route.reload()` refreshes the current rout only. The other routs are still the same. 
As a temporary solution I am using `location.reload();`  but this reloads the entire application when I hit on it.

Comment: Windows.location.href.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? More context might help you get an answer.

Comment: Concept doesn't make any sense. There is only ever one active route, how can you refresh something that isn't even active? This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Reloading the page is done by $window.location.reload(); Reloading the route is done by $route.reload();